# laravel voyager hasmany relationship not working

Tags: laravel, voyager

I'm using laravel voyager admin panel. I have two tables,

```
laradbs
  - id
  - name

regexes
  - id
  - name
  - laradb_id
```

Item has many regexes. This is the regexes relationship in laradbs bread.

[image]

And this is Laradb model.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Regex;

class Laradb extends Model
{
    public function regexes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Regex::class);
    }
}
```

But unfortunately when test bread I can't see any input field. It would be great if someone can help.

Comment: Did you ever solve this, i have exactly the same problem. I have a "Questions" model that hasMany "Tags" but in question editor i just get a label for tags, and no inputs to add tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/3643

If I understood correctly, Voyager does not have that feature.

So you just see "regex"es.

You should create relationship "belongs To" in "regexes"